# Git - find last time a file was modified across multiple repos?

Tags: git, github

I work at a company that builds a single app from > 100 smaller repos.

These repos all have a file in them, say `ivy.xml`, that shows the dependencies of the project on other projects and 3rd party libraries.

I'd like to be able to run a git command locally, on my dev machine to find out that last modified date of the `ivy.xml` file across all repos, and possibly see the log statement and diff of each change, even if I don't have the repos all checked out locally, which I never do of course, with there being > 100 of them!

It'd be awesome if this was sorted from most recently changed to oldest change.

**EDIT: Note that I'm open to installing additional tools that use git or github in my use case, to figure this out without downloading all the repos.**

Comment: With vanilla Git you'll have to clone every repository, working with Git history is local-only. Some Git servers provide an API to search history, what are you using to store your repositories? You may also consider making one repository for the app which has all of its smaller dependent repositories as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Good point - I'm open to other tools that make this easier, and will mention that in my question

Comment: @Brad Parks, are the repos public or private? I am about to push a script to help you with that.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a solution without downloading the repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to have the repos cloned, but then, this should work:

```
repos="path1 path2 path3"
file="your/file"
branchToCheck="origin/master"
for repo in repos; do cd $repo; edit=$(git log -n 1 --pretty='format:%ci %s %h' "$branchToCheck" "$file"); echo $edit $repo ; cd - ;done | sort -r
```

It will output something like:

```
2019-04-02 17:28:13 +0100 commit message COMMIT_HASH /path/to/repo1
2019-04-02 17:28:13 +0100 commit message COMMIT_HASH /path/to/repo2
```

Sorted by date.

Set the 3 variables with your needs, and use the 4th line as a one-liner.

EDIT:

Here is an alternative I just made using Github API, it requires `python3.6` or higher:

https://gist.github.com/padawin/adf58c682d41b0596c969beb212e35c6

It will need updating if the repos are not public (to provide authentication).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GitHub, you can use the `commits` method in the GitHub API to get the information you want.

Documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

The call you want is:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

For example, if you want to see the commits that modify `LICENSE.md` on https://github.com/clone95/Virgilio (picking a random repo trending on GitHub right now), this command will return that information:

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/clone95/Virgilio/commits?path=LICENSE.md'
```

The most minimalist parsing you could do is to grep for "date":

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/clone95/Virgilio/commits?path=LICENSE.md' | grep '"date"'
    "date": "2019-03-25T06:35:47Z"
    "date": "2019-03-25T06:35:47Z"
    "date": "2019-03-24T18:53:40Z"
    "date": "2019-03-24T18:53:40Z"
```

The results are actually a whole JSON record with lots of information. You could parse them carefully if you want, or just do a `head -1` after the grep above to get the most recent commit's author date, or take the second line for the committer date. I leave this part up to you, as well as looping over your repos and sorting the results as you need.

Caveat: the author and committer dates are of course not the push date. You'd have to cross reference with the event log for that, if you really needed it: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/